# Setting AJAX = "false" in this code

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have this code for the previous and next buttons but when I use them they do not return any data unless I refresh the page.  Is it as simple as adding some code to this to turn ajax to false or is there a better solution?  And how should this be handled? Thanks.

```
$links.each(function)
{
    var reverse = $(this).closest("." + prevLIClass).length;

    $(this).buttonMarkup(
    {
        "role" : "button",
        "theme" : "d",
        "iconpos" : "notext",
        "icon" : "arrow-" + (reverse ? "1" : "r")
    })
    .bind("vclick", function()
    {
        $.mobile.changePage($(this).attr("href"),{reverse : reverse});
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Please indent your code before you ask for help; this is very difficult to read. (There is an "edit" button at the bottom of your question.)

Comment: I hit control K, guess it didnt work.

Comment: Your code was indented *once* for markdown formatting so it shows up as a monospace code block. I wasn't asking about that; I was asking about indenting your code depending on how deeply nested it is. If you did have it correctly indented, it must have been lost when you pasted it. (Lee Taylor has already indented it for you, but next time you ask a question, please ensure your code is indented properly. Posting clean code will make it much easier for others to help you.)

Comment: yeah sorry, I had it indented guess it didnt copy over well.

Comment: Please, show your page html markup, or better yet create a jsFiddle